# React Native babel error: index.js: Unknown option: .dependencies

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, babel-loader

When I try to build the react-native app, it builds successfully but then I get this error when the app loads: `error: index.js: Unknown option: .dependencies. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.`

All the answers I found online are related to `react-native-dotenv` which I'm not using, so I'm stuck. I'm new to react native and don't know much about troubleshooting babel, so any help is appreciated. Nothing I've changed or removed gets me a different error. My package.json and babel.config.js are below.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "hescreeningapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "paper": "^0.12.17",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
    },
  },
};
```